# Problem in inserting UI after removing the ui

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to remove ui in shiny app. I have the code to remove each of the ui element separately with separate remove buttons. But additionally I would also like a generic delete button to remove all the inserted ui at once. For the task I tried the selector from insertUI and was able to delete all the added UIs.

But after this specific task i.e after removing all the UIs at once, shiny is not allowing me to insert any new UIs. It seems that the division ID has been removed permanently and couldn't be regenerated even after invoking the add button. How to solve this problem, please anyone guide me.

Below is the workable code and is adopted from stackoverflow

```
 library(shiny)

   ui <- fluidPage(


 sidebarLayout(
     sidebarPanel(

     actionButton('addBtn', 'Add input Set'),
     actionButton("remove","Delete"),


  tags$div(id='inputList')
),
mainPanel()
))

  server <- function(input, output) {

     observeEvent(input$addBtn, {

       # Increment by 1
       nr <- input$addBtn + 1

       # Creating a list of IDs based on our increments

       id <- paste0("input",nr)
       row_id <- paste0("newInput",nr)

       # Inserting the UIs

  insertUI(
       selector = '#inputList',
        ui=div(
         id = row_id,
         selectizeInput(
           inputId = id,
           choices = c("Stuff","to","input"),
           selected = c("Stuff"),
           label = "An Input:"          
      ),


    actionButton(paste0('removeBtn',nr), 'Remove')
    )
  )

  # Removes UI seperately 
  # Uses Seperate remove button for each ui

    observeEvent(input[[paste0('removeBtn',nr)]],{
      shiny::removeUI(
       selector = paste0("#newInput",nr)
    )
    })  

 })

 # Remove all the added UIs at once
 # InsertUI doesn't work after this


 observeEvent(input$remove,{

    removeUI(selector = "#inputList")


    })

 }

   shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's normal because your `removeUI` removes the `div(id = "inputList")`. So after that the `insertUI`s do not find this div.

Use instead:

```
removeUI(selector = "#inputList *", multiple = TRUE)
```

The CSS selector `#inputList *` selects all descendants of `#inputList`, but not `#inputList`.

Comment: Thanks for the swift solution. Can you also point me to a  place where I can learn about the CSS selectors in details with proper explainations.....This will help me in future!!